# Unusual problems with ajax and basic data submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

When I submit the ajax, I need to post three data parameters to `process.conversation.php`: `method`, `s_state`, and `c_id`. `s_state` and `c_id` are found in those two input values. Both variables are correctly being set. I use `alert(s_state)` and `alert(c_id)`, and they were both as I expected.

Everything works perfectly fine, except my `c_id` is not getting posted. If I change, in the ajax, `c_id: '1'`, the `1` will be posted as I would expect; however, when I use the variable c_id assigned to `1`, it does not get posted (or at least does not get posted with the value I was alerted with...I'm not sure which.) I do, however, get the success `toggleClass` in all instances.

Note: `s_state` works exactly as I would expect, as does `method`. If `s_state = '1'`, it gets posted with that variable. So, I have no idea why `c_id` is not working.

Any and all ideas are fully welcome. 
 
What might be going wrong?

jQuery/ajax:

```
$(".__conversation_s").click(function() {

var $thisS = $(this);
var s_state = $thisS.find("input[name='s_state']").val();
var c_id = $thisS.find("input[name='c_id']").val();

jQuery.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: "./process.conversation.php",
   data: {
       method: 'star_toggle', 
       s_state: 's_state',
       c_id: 'c_id'     
   },
   cache: True,
   success: function() {
       $thisS.toggleClass("__starred");
   }
});
});
```

and some html:

```
<div class='__conversation_s'>
    <input type='hidden' name='s_state' value="<?php echo $s_important; ?>">
    <input type='hidden' name='c_id' value="<?php echo $c_id; ?>">
</div>
```

Comment: If you use your browser's developer tools you'll be able to see exactly what is sent (and received)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax is incorrect in your data object. You have quotes around the variable names which means they are not variables but strings that contain the same letters as the variable name.

```
data: {
       method: 'star_toggle', 
       s_state: 's_state',
       c_id: 'c_id'  /* will send the string with letters `c` and `_` and `id` to server*/   
   }
```

Remove quotes from variables:

```
data: {
       method: 'star_toggle', 
       s_state: s_state,
       c_id: c_id 
   }
```

Comment: `star_toggle` should probably stay a string though.

Comment: @FelixKling  yup..thanks, I didn't look closely at vars that are created

Comment: Yes! wow...I feel daft. This works perfectly, i.e. removing the quotes around the two variables. Thank you!